# Drupal multi-site setup with sub-directories

Tags: drupal, subdirectory, single-instance

I have a multi-site setup with a single codebase.
Is it possible to have my sites directory set up like this with sub folders:
mysite.com in /home/drupal/sites/mysite.com

othersite1.com  in  /home/drupal/sites/cluster1/othersite1.com

othersite2.com  in  /home/drupal/sites/cluster1/othersite2.com

othersite3.com  in  /home/drupal/sites/cluster2/othersite3.com

othersite4.com  in  /home/drupal/sites/cluster2/othersite4.com

I'm trying to find a way to organize all my sites.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are using Drupal 7.  There is a file called sites.php in sites folder that you can alias the paths to your sites. If you are using < Drupal 7 you can make the directories as you propose and create symbolic links

```
 ln -s /home/drupal/sites/cluster1/othersite1.com othersite1.com
```

The way Drupal finds the site folder is explained in settings.php, read that.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm going to try that now. Do I need to cd into a certain directory before I run that command? My Drupal is installed at /home/drupal .

Comment: Can anyone tell me where I must cd into to run this command? Also to be clear, I don't want the directories cluster1, cluster2... to be sites themselves.

Comment: The directories will not be sites, only what is linked will be.  You should link the site.com -> your path in /sites.  So run that command in /sites. so ln -s /absolute/path/to/your/site yoursite.com in /sites